# Too many values to unpack in Python dictionary value split()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, text, nltk

I have a dictionary called `speech_dict` where `key` is a file's name and `value` is a speech (usually about 10,000 words). I'm trying to get the stem of each word; this is accomplished through some functions in the `nltk` module. Here's the code I have:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from nltk.stem import *
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer

stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")

spee_dict = speech_dict

for key,value in spee_dict:
    for i in value.split():
        i = stemmer.stem(i)
        i = i.decode('utf-8')
        spee_dict[key].add(i)
```

I get the following error:

`ValueError: too many values to unpack`

There are about 900 keys stored in `speech_dict`, and about 3.5 million words total to go through. How can I make this work?

Edit:

Alright, Delgan helped me add the stemmed word. How can I remove the original word, now?

I have this:

```
for key,value in spee_dict.items():
    for i in value.split():
        i_stemmed = stemmer.stem(i)
        i_stemmed = i_stemmed.decode('utf-8')
        spee_dict[key] += i_stemmed
        spee_dict[key] - I
```

But the `-` operand isn't supported by Unicode.

Comment: are you sure speech_dict is a dictionary, show how you defined it

Comment: Note that including the line-number the error corresponds to is very helpful.  (Even though it's fairly obvious here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for pairs of keys and values of a dictionnary, you have to use [`.items()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_items.htm).

```
for key, value in spee_dict.items():
```

If you do not, you are just iterating trough the keys. So, as the key is not a tuple, this raises an error because you can not unpack it.

Comment: I tried that earlier, but I just get the error: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'add'`, which is why I included the `decode` piece.

Comment: @GBR24 Then this is an other error which depends on what you stored in your dictionnary. Is there string? Sets?

Comment: It's string. The `values` are just speeches. For example, one `key` is 'obama4427' and the key starts 'my fellow americans I stand before you today'

Comment: I just checked the `type` of each word in the speeches and it came back as `Unicode`

Comment: @GBR24 If you wan to add a char to a string, you can not use `.add()`. You should use `spee_dict[key] += i`.

Comment: How can I remove the original word and replace it with its stem?

Comment: @GBR24 If you want to replace the previous value, can not you simply do `pee_dict[key] = i_stemmed`?

Comment: I don't think so, because I'm stemming each word in the speech. Wouldn't that just update `spee_dict[key]` with each stemmed word? It would never be the entire speech.

Comment: @GBR24 How, I think I understood. This is a bit complicated because manipulating string is not easy, but you could try something like: for 
    `split = value.split()
    for idx, i in enumerate(split):
        i_stemmed = stemmer.stem(i)
        i_stemmed = i_stemmed.decode('utf-8')
        split[idx] = i_stemmed`and then `spee_dict[key] = " ".join(split)`